# How can I expediently associate extra information with Enum members?

Tags: python, enums, idioms

Every once in a while, I find myself wanting to write something like this:

```
import enum

class Item(enum.Enum):
    SPAM = 'spam'
    HAM  = 'ham'
    EGGS = 'eggs'

    @property
    def price(self):
        if self is self.SPAM:
            return 123
        elif self is self.HAM:
            return 456
        elif self is self.EGGS:
            return 789
        assert False

item = Item('spam')
print(item)          # Item.SPAM
print(item.price)    # 123
```

This does exactly what I want: I have an enum `Item`, whose members can be obtained by calling the constructor with certain strings, and I can obtain the `price` of each `Item` by accessing a property. The problem is that when writing the `price` method I have to enumerate all the enum members in the method again. (Also, using this technique to associate mutable objects with members becomes a bit more complicated.)

I could instead write the enum like this:

```
import enum

class Item(enum.Enum):
    SPAM = ('spam', 123)
    HAM  = ('ham' , 456)
    EGGS = ('eggs', 789)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return super().value[0]
 
    @property
    def price(self):
        return super().value[1]

item = Item.SPAM
print(item)          # Items.SPAM
print(item.value)    # spam
print(item.price)    # 123
```

Now I don’t have to repeat members in the method. The problem becomes that by doing this I lose the ability to obtain `Item.SPAM` by calling `Item('spam')`:

```text
>>> Item('spam')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py", line 360, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py", line 677, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: 'spam' is not a valid Item
```

This is important to me, because I want to be able to pass the `Item` class as the `type=` keyword argument to `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument`.

Is there a way to associate extra values with enum members without repeating myself, while simultaneously retaining the ability to construct members from their ‘primary’ values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the stdlib `Enum` you would need to create your own `__new__`:

```
import enum

class Item(enum.Enum):
    #
    SPAM = 'spam', 123
    HAM  = 'ham', 456
    EGGS = 'eggs', 789
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, price):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.price = price
        return obj
```

If this is something you have to do a lot, you can use the [`aenum` library](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup> instead.

```
import aenum

class Item(aenum.Enum):
    #
    _init_ = 'value price'
    #
    SPAM = 'spam', 123
    HAM  = 'ham', 456
    EGGS = 'eggs', 789
```

Either way, you end with:

```
>>> item = Item.SPAM

>>> print(item)          # Items.SPAM
Item.SPAM

>>> print(item.value)    # spam
spam

>>> print(item.price)    # 123
123

>>> Item('spam')
<Item.SPAM: 'spam'>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score -3):

you can use `__init__`?

```
class Item(enum.Enum):
    SPAM = ('spam', 123)
    HAM  = ('ham' , 456)
    EGGS = ('eggs', 789)

    def __init__(self, item_type, price):
        self._type = item_type
        self._price = price

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._type

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price


In []: item = Item.SPAM
In []: item.name, item.value, item.price
Out[]: ('SPAM', 'spam', 123)

In []: Item.SPAM
Out[]: <Item.SPAM: ('spam', 123)>
```

`Item('spam')` isn't going to work because `EnumMeta.__call__` doesn't support it. Below is from the [source from cpython 3.8 `enum.py` (`l.313`)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6900a515c8410795f9a8ef2ad38740847a919b6d/Lib/enum.py#L313)

```
def __call__(cls, value, names=None, *, module=None, qualname=None, type=None, start=1):
    """
    Either returns an existing member, or creates a new enum class.

    This method is used both when an enum class is given a value to match
    to an enumeration member (i.e. Color(3)) and for the functional API
    (i.e. Color = Enum('Color', names='RED GREEN BLUE')).

    When used for the functional API:

    `value` will be the name of the new class.

    `names` should be either a string of white-space/comma delimited names
    (values will start at `start`), or an iterator/mapping of name, value pairs.

    `module` should be set to the module this class is being created in;
    if it is not set, an attempt to find that module will be made, but if
    it fails the class will not be picklable.

    `qualname` should be set to the actual location this class can be found
    at in its module; by default it is set to the global scope.  If this is
    not correct, unpickling will fail in some circumstances.

    `type`, if set, will be mixed in as the first base class.
    """
    if names is None:  # simple value lookup
        return cls.__new__(cls, value)
    # otherwise, functional API: we're creating a new Enum type
    return cls._create_(
            value,
            names,
            module=module,
            qualname=qualname,
            type=type,
            start=start,
            )

def __contains__(cls, member):
    if not isinstance(member, Enum):
        raise TypeError(
            "unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': '%s' and '%s'" % (
                type(member).__qualname__, cls.__class__.__qualname__))
    return isinstance(member, cls) and member._name_ in cls._member_map_ 
...
```

so instead of `Item('spam')`, I'd say `Item.get('spam')` is better to get to `Item.SPAM`. It will also fail gracefully if the query doesn't exist

```
    ...
    @property
    def __items(self):
        return {v.value: cls.__getattr__(k) for k, v in cls.__members__.items()}

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, item):
        return cls.__items.get(item)
    ...

In []: Item.get('spam')
Out[]: <Item.SPAM: ('spam', 123)>    
In []: Item.get('spamm') # returns None
```

Comment: `Item('spam')` raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: Ok I have to say that's a weird looking syntax for what you want to achieve, i really don't know if that's actually possible and I recommend not to pursue that. Instead I think I have a workaround that might work just as well without looking "off" semantically. As it was what you typed invoke an impression you're trying to instantiate an `Item` object with `spam` parameter, instead of trying to access`Item.SPAM`.