# Indexing Python dict with string keys using Enums

Tags: python, dictionary, enums

Is there a way to index a dict using an enum?

e.g. I have the following Enum and dict:

```
class STATUS(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active"

d = { "active": 1 }
```

I'd like to add the appropriate logic to the class STATUS in order to get the following result:

```py
d[STATUS.ACTIVE]
# returns 1
```

I understand that the type of STATUS.ACTIVE is not a string.. But is there a way around other than declaring the dict using STATUS.ACTIVE instead of "active"?

Also: looking for a solution other than adding a class property or .value

Comment: would d[STATUS.ACTIVE.value] do?

Comment: Technically yes.. but meant to add: without adding extra dot items after - e.g. not a property function (actually already have that implemented and trying to see if I can do without). Editing the text to add this nuance.

Comment: You can make the STATUS enum derive from str as well. "class STATUS(str, Enum):"

Comment: @Nelala_: please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ElmovanKielmo solution will work, however you can also achieve your desired result by making the STATUS Enum derive from str as well

```
from enum import Enum


class STATUS(str, Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active"


d = {"active": 1}

print(d[STATUS.ACTIVE])
# prints 1
```

Please keep in mind, that [when inheriting from str, or any other type, the resulting enum members are also that type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727103/what-are-the-caveats-of-inheriting-from-both-str-and-enum)

Comment: Great solve! Thank you @Nelala_ this may be for another post on here (happy to create a new one if folks feel it would be appropriate), but I also have the case where my enum is of the form:

class STATUS(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active",  1

(so it's a tuple) ... effectively same question, where I want print(d[STATUS.ACTIVE]) to print 1 for the same d

Comment: Same solution as here, but deriving from tuple instead of str | "class STATUS(tuple, Enum):" :)

Comment: Well, this causes the dict indexing to error out as it expects an str rather than tuple in this new scenario... Any way around?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your comment. So you want to return only the first item in the tuple by default? Some hacky solution, like custom dicts would probably work, but I think you'll have a better chance at an answer if you post this as a new question.

Comment: @alps: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66428177/208880) should work for your secondary question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your custom dictionary class:

```
from collections import UserDict
from enum import Enum

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, Enum):
            key = key.value
        return super().__getitem__(key)

class STATUS(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active"

d = MyDict({ "active": 1 })
d[STATUS.ACTIVE]
```